# Python: how to display exact decimal value

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary like

```
>> dic = {'yearly': 79.00, 'monthly': 59.00}
```

when the dic is printed the, it removes the last zero from the decimal number.

```
>> print dic
>> {'monthly': 59.0, 'yearly': 79.0}
```

How to get the original value as `59.00` not as `59.0` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: another option would be to use the `decimal.Decimal` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you print a number, you could do

```
x = 5
print '%.2f' % x
```

where the 2 specifies u want 2 decimal place

alternatively, the more updated/versatile version is

```
print '{:.2f}'.format(x)
```

if you really want your dict object to print nicely, you could create a custom class that specifies the `__str__` function to print the dict however you want to print it